# Best way to encrypt then decrypt in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, encryption, laravel-5.1

I know my question is subjective, but I have not found a solution anywhere. I want to first encrypt and then decrypt a string, but don't know how to do this.

There are so many methods available on Google, but none of them is secure.

Comment: Explain in few words to us what kind of methods did you found and why you think they are insecure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best way but you can take a look at the [encryption facade](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/encryption).